# Letter counting function

Tags: python, list-comprehension, counter, alphabetical, alphabetical-sort

I need to define a function that takes a string and counts the number of letters of the alphabet(only lower case)in the input, for instance if I input "jack" it would return:

```
a=1,b=0,c=1,d=0,...,j=1,k=1,...,z=0.
```

So I implemented the following :

```
def l_count(str):
    str.lower()
    for ch in str:
        return str.count('a')
```

Which only returns the number of 'a' in the string.
Since i don't want to do it for all the alphabet I thought about implementing a list comprehension like this :

```
al = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z'))] 
def l_count(str):
    str.lower()
    for character in str:
        return str.count(al)
```

But I get an error :

```
must be str, not list
```

I don't know how to change it since I get the same error.

Comment: That's because `al` is a list

Comment: the error message is very clear, isn't it?

Comment: I know but how can I change it

Comment: Although it is tempting, don't call your string `str` - that is a built-in function.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I changed my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

x = 'jack'

c = Counter(dict.fromkeys(ascii_lowercase, 0))
c.update(Counter(x))

print(*(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in c.items()), sep=',')

a=1,b=0,c=1,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0,i=0,j=1,k=1,l=0,m=0,n=0,o=0,p=0,q=0,r=0,s=0,t=0,u=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0
```

You may wish to add logic to `lowercase` your string, exclude punctuation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Counter` object for this

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(x for x in string.lower() if x.isalpha())
```

This transforms all characters in `string` to lowercase, checks whether they are alphabetic, and then Counts all of the characters.

Comment: This does not include all those `...=0` counts OP seems to want to have.

Comment: True, however if you use `counter.get('<character>', 0)` to retrieve the count, it will return 0 when a character is not present.

Comment: That's true, too. In fact, you don't even have to `get`, you can also just do `counter[x]` for any `x` not in the string and will get `0`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this one:

```
import string
def l_count(stra):
    stra = stra.lower()
    return {i:stra.count(i) for i in string.ascii_lowercase}
```

Comment: The method `str.lower` has a return value. It does not modify the instance internally. In your case it should be `stra = stra.lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the chars that are present in the string, then you can use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_counter = Counter('jack')
>>> my_counter
Counter({'j': 1, 'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'k': 1})
```

If you want to show the counts for all lowercase letters, you can loop now like this:

```
>>> import string
>>> ','.join('{}={}'.format(ch, my_counter.get(ch, 0)) for ch in string.ascii_lowercase)
'a=1,b=0,c=1,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0,i=0,j=1,k=1,l=0,m=0,n=0,o=0,p=0,q=0,r=0,s=0,t=0,u=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0'

>>> for ch in string.ascii_lowercase:
...     print(ch, my_counter.get(ch, 0))
a 1
b 0
c 1
d 0
e 0
f 0
g 0
h 0
i 0
j 1
k 1
l 0
m 0
n 0
o 0
p 0
q 0
r 0
s 0
t 0
u 0
v 0
w 0
x 0
y 0
z 0
```